# C++ Compile-Time Conditional Run-Time Statements

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

Is there a way to, at compile-time, decide on one of two run-time code paths? I am aware that function overloading can be used to accomplish this feat, but then the code size increases because both of my functions are compiled and linked into the program. Is there a way to avoid this size overhead?

Essentially, what I want to do is:

```
#include <boost/mpl/if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_abstract.hpp>

template <class T>
    class X
{
    public:
        void copy_t(T &old_t)
        {
            //
            // if T is abstract, (meaning that t is a pointer)
            //
            t = old_t.clone();

            //
            // else
            //
            t = old_t;
        }   

    private: 
        typename boost::mpl::if_<boost::is_abstract<T>, T *, T>::type t;
};
```

The only way I know involves overloaded member functions:

```
template <class T>
    class X
{   
    public:
        void copy_t(T &old_t)
        {   
            t = make_copy(old_t, t); 
        }   

    private:
        T *make_copy(T &old_t, T *t) 
        {   
            return old_t.clone();
        }   

        T &make_copy(T &old_t, T &t) 
        {   
            return old_t;
        }   

        typename boost::mpl::if_<boost::is_abstract<T>, T *, T>::type t;
};
```

But now, two `make_copy` member functions are compiled and linked into the program, even though `X` may only ever be instantiated with an abstract class template parameter, in which case, only one of them is needed.

Comment: Won't the optimizer remove the uncalled functions?

Comment: Let me make this clear: you are concerned about the extra cost of a one-liner function in your final executable?

Comment: Also note that you are making quite a few assumptions in the code, for example, every objects of a non-abstract type is a complete object. I.e. If you have a type that extends a different non-abstract type, and the function is called on the intermediate type, you will be slicing. Your interface seems to offer the *will do what's best in each case* promise (either copy/clone), but then does not always deliver the promise.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas just wanted to find out what the right way to do these kinds of things is. I'm not sure I understand your second comment - how can an object of a non-abstract type be incomplete? Can you please give an example?

Comment: In this context, the opposite of *complete* would be *subobject*, rather than *incomplete*. The example is a inheritance hierarchy `I <- B <- D` (`I` being an interface/abstract, `B` being a non-abstract base class, `D` the derived class). The check that you are performing makes `I` different from both `B` and `D`, which means that if you instantiate your template with `B` the argument will be *copied*, which will cause slicing if its actual (*complete*) type is `D`. A more interesting test (also more complex) would be to detect whether `clone()` exists and act on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your examples, it looks like the functions are members of a class
template.  If so, they will only be instantiated if they are actually
used; if overload resolution always chooses one of them, the other will
never be instantiated.

This is a critical rule for a lot of meta-programming techniques.  It's
not rare in such cases that the function which isn't instantiated would
cause compile time errors if it was instantiated.